# Get ID from URL and write to data table

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have Interwier table

here is table code

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Interwiers] (
[Interwier_id] INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[FIO]          NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
[Email]        NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
[Telephone]    NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
[Birthday]     DATETIME       NOT NULL,
[City]         NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
[Salary]       NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
[English]      NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
[Interview_Id] INT            NULL,
[Status]       NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Interwier_id] ASC),
CONSTRAINT [FK_Interwiers_ToTable] FOREIGN KEY ([Interview_Id]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Interviews] ([Interview_Id]) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

);

Here is how my View looks like

[image: My View]

I have link like this `http://localhost:51542/Interwier/Welcome/2093`  where 2093 is Interview_Id

Now my action for writing to datatable looks like this

```
 public ActionResult Welcome()
    {
        return View();
    }

    // POST: Interwier/Create
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Welcome([Bind(Include = "Id,FIO,Email,Telephone,Birthday,City,English,Salary")] Interwier interwierModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.InterwierModels.Add(interwierModel);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("WebCamCheck");
        }

        return View(interwierModel);
    }
```

I need to write id from link to table. How I can do this?

**UPDATE**

I try solution with ViewBag and face problem

value not writing to Interview_Id

HiddenFor is not null
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kI6iJ.png)

Why so? Why it not writing?

**UPDATE**

Problem is solved

@Shyju method works. Thank's dude

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass it through your view (form).

The below example uses ViewBag dictionary to pass the data from action method to the view. If you have a view model, add a property for this interview id and use that to pass the data to the view (*and back to the httppost action method when the form is submitted*)

```
public ActionResult Welcome(int id)
{
   ViewBag.InterviewId=id;
   return View();
}
```

Now in your view, keep this value in a hidden field inside your form.

```
<input type="hidden" name="Interview_Id" value="@ViewBag.InterviewId" />
```

And include the `Interview_Id` property to your `Bind` attributes `Include` list   When the form is submitted, the interviewId value will be available in that property.

```
public ActionResult Welcome([Bind(Include = "Id,FIO,Email,Telephone,Birthday,
                        City,English,Salary,Interview_Id")] Interwier interwierModel)
{
    // to do : Use interwierModel.Interview_Id as needed
    // to do : Return something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to pass `id` to the view and add this id to hidden field of property `Interview_Id` so your action will be like this

```
public ActionResult Welcome(int id)
{
   ViewBag.Id=id;
   return View();
}
```

and in view add value of hidden field

```
 @Html.HiddenFor(x=> x.Interview_Id,new {@Value = ViewBag.Id })
```

In action it will be added to the model and add `Interview_Id`

```
[Bind(Include = "Interview_Id,Id,FIO,Email,Telephone,Birthday,City,English,Salary")
```

Comment: I do like this, but Interview_Id is null in table

Comment: @E.S my bad its capital V in value